QGIS Copy and Rotate Polygon Features to Multiple Point Locations Based On Point Layer
Summary: I am looking to copy a custom polygon layer (with multiple features) to numerous point locations based on the locations of a point layer in QGIS. This should also rotate the polygon layer placed based on an attribute in the point layer. I am thinking this should operate similar to "Rectangles, ovals, diamonds" tool except instead of one of the three pre-defined shapes in this tool, the shape is based on another pre-defined layer. In other words, I am looking to "stamp" a polygon on multiple points and rotate this "stamp" using an attribute.
Detail: I'm building a map of Streetlight Distribution Pattern based on GIS data I have for approx. 6,000 streetlights. I have a point layer with location, light type, and direction of fixture. For each light type I have a specific light pattern that I can build into QGIS. I am looking to copy these specific light patterns to each point location and rotate these respectively. I did this manually for an example, but looking for help finding a way to automate this for the rest of my points.
For example, a SHP containing multiple features correlating to the lamps throw pattern:

An example of how this SHP should be "copied" and rotated on each point layer for a street. I did this manually, but looking for an automatic method for the remaining 6,000 locations.


Your polygon layer have seven rows in it, on for each red color (light intensity?) ?

Correct - Polygon layer has 7 separate features correlating to light intensity. Basically rings that surround the fixture 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, and 0.6 foot-candle.
